# powercli Get-VM NOT matching Tag

Tags: powershell, tags, powercli

I am using Tags to filter VM / identify special configuration.

```
Get-VM -Tag TEST
```

Now I want to get all VMs NOT matching a tag .... Is there a way to do that without an extra loop to remove all items matching the Tag ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As it seems, no. But using another loop is not a bad solution.

Should be something like:

```
Get-VM -Name * | ?{$_.Tag -ne "Test"}
```

Or if `VirtualMachine` doesn't have a `Tag` property, you should try with `Get-View`:

```
Get-View -Name * | ?{$_ .Tag -ne "Test"} | Get-VM
```

Answer (score 0):

I was looking at this, and I used the `-contains`/`-notcontains` comparison operator instead of `-eq`/`-ne`, as it always returns the a boolean expression. If you have more than one tag, it might not work properly.

```
$VMs = get-vm 

foreach ($VM in $VMs){
    If (((Get-Tagassignment $VM).Tag.Name -notcontains "Prod"){
         Whatever you want if it doesn't contain prod.
    }
}
```